# Trying to edit a report type from a managed package iWave

Tags: managed-package, custom-report-type

I was trying to edit the layout of a custom report type that came with a managed package iWave. There is no button to edit the layout and I see only the preview layout button. I would like to enable all the 66 fields in that custom object to the report type so that users can use them for reporting purpose. I am not sure how can that be done. After reading the notification, does it me that we have to upgrade to use those fields?
[image]